# sphinxsearch-0.9 in mediawiki-1.32.0 error

Tags: mediawiki, sphinx

```
2019/01/14 12:04:51 [error] 21549#21549: *3558 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class SphinxMWSearch contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SearchDatabase::doSearchTextInDB, SearchDatabase::doSearchTitleInDB) in /var/opt/www/extensions/SphinxSearch/SphinxMWSearch.php on line 15" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.122.1, server: wiki.yuyizhi.org, request: "GET /index.php?title=Special:%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2&search=sphinx HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "wiki.yuyizhi.org"
```

FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class SphinxMWSearch contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (SearchDatabase::doSearchTextInDB, SearchDatabase::doSearchTitleInDB) in /var/opt/www/extensions/SphinxSearch/SphinxMWSearch.php on line 15", client: 192.168.122.1, server: wiki.abc.com, request: "GET /api.php?action=opensearch&search=bai&namespace=0 HTTP/1.0", host: "wiki.abc.com"

Comment: Seems like the SphinxMWSearch  class you using was probably built for an old version of PHP, that was less strict about how classes defined. The code will need updating to latest practices.

Answer (score 0):

The SearchDatabase class that SphinxSearch extends was changed from REL1_31 to REL1_32. It now requires you to define `doSearchTextInDB` and `doSearchTitleInDB` methods.

See REL1_31 https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/REL1_31/php/classSearchDatabase.html
vs REL1_32 https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/REL1_32/php/classSearchDatabase.html

This is sortof mentioned in the patch notes if you search for `Search` under deprecation (note this is a Backwards compatibility break instead) https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Release_notes/1.32#Compatibility:

> Overriding SearchEngine::{searchText,searchTitle,searchArchiveTitle} in extending classes is deprecated. Extend related doSearch* methods instead.

If you are like me and not comfortable fixing the extension yourself, you will have to wait for one of the extension contributors to update the extension to work with REL1_32. Until then you will have to stay on REL1_31 if you wish to use the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding these two empty functions to `SphinxMWSearch.php` under the definition of `SphinxMWSearch` class seems to do the trick. It makes it stop complaining and - as far as I can tell - search function is working fine.

```
function doSearchTextInDB($term) {
}
function doSearchTitleInDB($term) {
}
```

Hopefully developers of this extension will come up with a proper fix soon.